# How to show a message box once all threads have finished execution?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, data-structures

Want to break down a very heavy function using threads and show a message box when the work is completed.

Following is similar code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < tests.Count; index/=3)
{
    System.Threading.Thread t =
        new System.Threading.Thread(
            () => SomeFunction(tests.GetRange(start, 3)));
    t.Start();
}
```

Want to show a message box once all these threads have completed execution and the whole work is done. How do i do it?
Join won't work as it would result in same time as without using threads.

Comment: Are you aware of `Parallel.For` with description here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: You do realize that your loop will always execute one time, at most, right?

Comment: @CareyGregory, no, it will execute forever, unless `tests.Count == 0`

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Oops, my bad.  You're right.

Answer (score 7):

Throw away the old school threads if you're in .Net4.0+. Use Task paralell library.

```
var uiContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var tasks = ...;//Start tasks
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, antecedents =>
{
   //Show messagebox here 
},CancellationToken.None,TaskContinuationOptions.None,uiContext);
```

Wait asynchronously using `ContinueWhenAll` and execute the callback in UIThread using `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`.

Comment: In the for loop:
    var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeFunction(cnt, tests.GetRange(start, 3)));
    tasks.Add(task);

Then:
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), antecedents =>
            {
                //Show messagebox here 
                if (timer != null)
                    timer.Stop();
                 MessageBox.Show(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
            });

However somehow the Somefunction() is not getting executed

Comment: Debug and see whether loop is executed, if yes add a messagebox in `SomeFunction` and see whether that is executed

Answer (score 3):

It's easier if you use tasks rather than threads:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int index = 0; index < tests.Count; index/=3)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeFunction(tests.GetRange(start, 3)));
    tasks.Add(tasks);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

If you really want to use threads, an option is to use wait handles:

```
var waitHandles = new List<EventWaitHandle>();
for (int index = 0; index < tests.Count; index/=3)
{
    var waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    waitHandles.Add(waitHandle);
    System.Threading.Thread t =
        new System.Threading.Thread(
            () =>
            {
                SomeFunction(tests.GetRange(start, 3));
                waitHandle.Set();
            });
    t.Start();
}
WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray());
MessageBox.Show("Done!");
```

Note that if you call this on the UI thread, the UI will be frozen until all threads complete. If you want to avoid that, a better option is to use `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll`, as suggested in Sriram Sakthivel's answer.

BTW, are you sure about the `index/=3` part? It will cause the loop to run forever if `test.Count > 0`...

Comment: If this is called from UI thread `WaitAll` is not the right choice

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, good point. I updated my answer to mention that and referred to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't you use `Parallel.Foreach()` instead and it will automatically will wait for all. Something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 10), i => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", i, GetTotal());
});
```

Comment: Yes, except that it only supports linear incrementation of the loop variable (i.e. `i++`)... the OP uses `index /= 3` (which doesn't make much sense IMO).